# Find postive integer $x$ with $x>1$ and $\dfrac{x^6-1}{x-1}$ is perfect square

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> Find positive integer $x$ with $x>1$ and $\dfrac{x^6-1}{x-1}$ is perfect square.

**My try:** Let $\dfrac{x^6-1}{x-1}=y^2$, so $(x^4+x^2+1)(x+1)=y^2$.

Let $d= \gcd(x+1,x^4+x^2+1)$.
And
$d \vert x^4+x^2+1=(x^2+x+1)(x^2-x+1)$, because $d\vert x+1$ so $d\vert 2$.

Case 1: $d=1$. If $d=1$ so $(x^4+x^2+1)$,$(x+1)$ is perfect square and $(x^2+\dfrac{1}{2})^2\le x^4+x^2+1\le(x^2+1)^2$ so no satisfactory solution.

Case 2: $d=2$. If $d=2$ so $\dfrac{x^4+x^2+1}{2}$,$\dfrac{x+1}{2}$ is perfect square. 
But now I stuck. Please give me a hint. Thank you.

Comment: Wait, doesn't the gcd have to divide $3$, not $2$?  If $x \equiv 2 \pmod 3$, then $x+1$ and $x^2 - x + 1$ are both divisible by $3$.

Comment: @RaviFernando In particular, $x^4+x^2+1\equiv3\pmod{x+1}$.

Comment: @tompi2394 A minor point with your Case 1 is regarding $(x^2+\dfrac{1}{2})^2\le x^4+x^2+1\le(x^2+1)^2$. Both $\le$ can be $\lt$ instead, but with the second one being more important since you want $x^4 + x^2 + 1$ to be less than that perfect square.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've got the right idea, but as [Kenta S's comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4510682/find-postive-integer-x-with-x1-and-dfracx6-1x-1-is-perfect-square#comment9470655_4510682) indicates, it's $d \mid 3$ (since $x \equiv -1 \pmod{x+1}$ means $x^4 + x^2 + 1 \equiv (-1)^4 + (-1)^2 + 1 \equiv 3 \pmod{x + 1}$), not $d \mid 2$, so the other option is $d = 3$. For that case, for some integers $m$ and $n$, we have

$$x^4 + x^2 + 1 = 3m^2, \; \; x + 1 = 3n^2 \; \; \to \; \; x \equiv -1 \pmod{3} \tag{1}\label{eq1A}$$

With your factorization of

$$x^4+x^2+1=(x^2+x+1)(x^2-x+1) \tag{2}\label{eq2A}$$

note that

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
\gcd(x^2+x+1,x^2-x+1) & = \gcd(x^2+x+1,x^2+x+1-(x^2-x+1)) \\
& = \gcd(x^2+x+1,2x)
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{3}\label{eq3A}$$

Since $x^2 + x + 1 = x(x+1) + 1$ is always odd, and $\gcd(x^2+x+1,x) = 1$, this means that $x^2+x+1$ and $x^2-x+1$ are always relatively prime. With \eqref{eq1A} giving that $x \equiv -1 \pmod{3}$, then $x^2 - x + 1 \equiv (-1)^2 - (-1) + 1 \equiv 3 \equiv 0 \pmod{3}$. Thus, from the first part of \eqref{eq1A} and using \eqref{eq2A}, there are integers $s$ and $t$ where $m = st$ and

$$x^2 + x + 1 = s^2, \; \; x^2 - x + 1 = 3t^2 \tag{4}\label{eq4A}$$

However, $x^2 \lt x^2 + x + 1 \lt (x + 1)^2$, so the first part of \eqref{eq4A} is not possible. This means there are **no** integers $x \gt 1$ where $\frac{x^6 - 1}{x - 1}$ is a perfect square.

Comment: +1. Can we generalize  this statement for $\frac {x^n-1}{x-1}$?

Comment: At $n=2$ and $x=3$ it is a perfect square you can't generalize

Comment: @abcdefu $n=2$ is trivial. I meant $n≥6$

Comment: @User I'm not aware offhand of any simple generalization for $\frac{x^n-1}{x-1}$ for all $n$. For example, with $n = 5$ (although you wrote $n \ge 6$, this is still instructive), the [answer](/a/3740962) to [Find when $\frac{x^5-1}{x-1}$ is a perfect square?](/q/3740956) shows that there's just one solution for $x = 3$ giving $121 = 11^2$. However, the technique there shows that, with odd $n$, for all sufficiently large $x$, then $\frac{x^n-1}{x-1}$ is between $2$ perfect squares, so there are only a finite number of possible solutions. Even $n$, however, are generally more problematic.

Comment: At my case 2, i still stuck, can you give me a hint please. Thanh you.

Comment: @tompi2394 Your case 2, i.e., with $d = 2$, is incorrect. As explained in Kenta S's comment and at the top of my answer, the only possible values of $d$ are $1$ or $3$, with it never being $2$. Also note that $x^2 + x + 1 = x(x + 1) + 1$ is always odd since either $x$ or $x + 1$ is even. Similarly, $x^2 - x + 1 = x(x - 1) + 1$ is also always odd. Thus, $d = \gcd(x^2 + x + 1, x^2 - x + 1)$ is always odd.

Comment: @tompi2394 My above comment had a wrong expression for $d$. Instead, you have $d \mid x^4 + x^2 + 1 = x^2(x^2 + 1)  + 1$, but since either $x^2$ or $x^2 + 1$ is even, then $x^4 + x^2 + 1$ is odd, so $d$ can't be $2$.

Comment: Oh I know why i'm wrong. Thank you very much.

Comment: @JohnOmielan  It seems to me that even powers should be *simpler* given what we've seen above. If $n=2p$ for prime $p$, $(x^n-1)/(x-1)$ factorizes as $(x+1)\cdot A(x)B(x)$, where $A(x)$ and $B(x)$ are coprime polynomials (like $x^2+x+1,x^2-x-1$ above). Hence the only way for such a number to be a square is if $x+1=A(x)B(x)$, which is impossible as the degrees of both $A(x)$ and $B(x)$ are larger than $1$. $n=4p$ has the same result, but with $(x+1)(x^2+1)=A(x)B(x)$, same as previously but the orders of magnitude are even larger. For odd $n$, the pattern is harder to discern.

Comment: Note that this arises from the fact that $x^n-1=\prod_{d \mid n} \Phi_d(x)$, something I learned while looking at this problem. In addition, $\Phi_{k}\cdot \Phi_{2k} = \Phi'_{4k}$, where the prime indicates the "conjugate" of the polynomial in the sense of the positive and negative signs. (That is, $x^2+x+1$ and $x^2-x+1$ are "conjugates")

Answer (score 4):

There's a simpler solution if you consider $\frac{x^6 - 1}{x - 1} = (x^2 + x + 1)(x^3 + 1)$. Let $d = \gcd(x^2 + x + 1, x^3 + 1)$, then $d \mid x^2 + x + 1 \mid x^3 - 1$ and $d \mid x^3 + 1$. So $d \mid 2$ but the number $x^2 + x + 1 = x(x + 1) + 1$ is odd. Therefore $d = 1$ and the numbers $x^2 + x + 1$ and $x^3 + 1$ are perfect squares. But for $x > 1$ we have $x^2 < x^2 + x + 1 < (x + 1)^2$. So there's no such $x$.

Comment: You can go even simpler: $(x^6-1)/(x-1)=(x+1)(x^2+x+1)(x^2-x+1)$, and $(x^2+x+1, x^2-x+1)=1$. To have a square, we require $x+1=(x^2+x+1)(x^2-x+1)$. Which is impossible for $x>0$.

Comment: @EricSnyder Why *"we require $x + 1 = (x^2 + x + 1)(x^2 - x + 1)$"*? $36 = 2 \times 9 \times 2$ and $\gcd(9, 2) = 1$ but $2 \not= 9 \times 2$.

Comment: Ah, indeed, that was a step too far, *mea culpa.* Neither $x^2+x+1$ nor $x^2-x+1$ are squares, but nor are they necessarily squarefree. However, the non-squarefree ones are few and far between, and we don't hit one where they're both squarefree until $x=68$, where the remaining factors are $(3)(13)(31)=1209$. So, I guess not proof there but a heuristic. I suspect proof would be doable, but no longer quite as simple. :)

Comment: Also, when you prove $d=1$ and therefore $x^3+1$ must be a square, Catalan's conjecture (Mihailescu's theorem) tells us that the only solution in the positive integers *for that condition* is $x=2$. But $x=2$ does not satisfy any other requirement, including the original query; therefore, there are no solutions.

Comment: @on1921379 same my idea but I can’t solve with $d=2$, thank you.